# csv file from yaml in python

Tags: python, csv, yaml

```
4:
- a: [0.6511928334730416, -0.6444996859128429, 0.40070930065859994]
  b: [-70.26386506067132, 19.563101216582368, 315.91419304402643]
  c: [462, 429, 401, 389]
  d: 1
5:
- e: [0.6511928334730416, -0.6444996859128429, 0.40070930065859994]
  f: [-70.26386506067132, 19.563101216582368, 315.91419304402643]
  g: [462, 429, 401, 389]
  h: 1
```

This is my yml format and I have to extract only the values of key c and g from it and create a csv file. I am new to python.
 Can anyone guide me here
thanks in advance

Comment: is that two yaml files ?

Comment: no a single one

Comment: We are here to guide you when you have problems, not to guide you by giving you the answer.. Did you tried something?

Comment: yes..i tried by converting it to a dictionary.. import yaml                                           
    ...: MyDict = yaml.load(open('filepath))                                                              then i can acess the each key value pair by doing MyDIct[keyvalue] but that prints the entire subsection in section 1 but i need only the third value from each section..kind of confused here

Comment: for it in MyDict['4'].items():
         print('{} ==> {}'.format(*it))
returns keyerror: '4'

Comment: could you please edit the question and add to it what you have tried. It will help others better understand you problem

Comment: The answer provided by https://stackoverflow.com/users/8393004/vikas-damodar appears to do what you asked for. If so, you should, please, mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your yaml converted to dict is similar to this :

```
d = {4:
       {
      'a': [0.6511928334730416, -0.6444996859128429, 0.40070930065859994],
      'b': [-70.26386506067132, 19.563101216582368, 315.91419304402643],
      'c': [462, 429, 401, 389],
      'd': 1
       },
    5:
     {'e': [0.6511928334730416, -0.6444996859128429, 0.40070930065859994],
      'f': [-70.26386506067132, 19.563101216582368, 315.91419304402643],
      'g': [462, 429, 401, 380],
      'h': 1
     }
    }
```

The following code you can try to convert the values to CSV :

```
import csv  
import itertools  

# taking only the values of keys 'c' and 'g'
li = [i[j] for i in d.values()  for j in i.keys()  if j == "c" or j == "g"]

# the above list of list making a flat list for better result
merged = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(li))

with open("filename.csv",'w') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, lineterminator='\n')
    # If you want first list to csv you can use li instead of merged 
    wr.writerow(merged)
```

Answer (score 0):

Through looping you can do but this is just an idea you can have better also

**try this:-**

```
import yaml
MyDict = yaml.load(open('example.yaml'))

    key = ['c','g']
    for i in MyDict.values():
        for j  in i:
            for k in key:
                if k in j:
                    print(j.get(k))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and tested this

```
import yaml

with open(r'test.yaml') as file:
    documents = yaml.full_load(file)

    for item, doc in documents.items():
        print(item, ":", doc)
```